# Need an example of  finitely generated graded algebra such that  each its graded subspace has  infinite dimension.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, co.combinatorics

More accurately, let $\displaystyle A=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}A_i$ be a finitely  generated graded algebra over say $\mathbb{Q}$  but $\dim A_i=\infty$  for each $i.$   Is it possible?

Comment: Think about how you can generate the elements of $A_1$ if it is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: This question has already been answered, so maybe it's not that important, but the title is wrong.  It says "example of a not finitely generated graded algebra", when the question asks for a finitely generated graded algebra.

Comment: yes, I already  correct it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbb Q[x,y]$ with $x$ in degree 0, and $y$ in degree 1.

If you want your generators to be in positive degrees, then what you're asking for is impossible.